# How to access Navision table schema?

Tags: biztalk, navision

How can we access the Navision Table schema?
I know that Navision can publish the tables as a page service that can be accessed outside.
But is this the only way or there is a some other way in which Navision can helps us in doing this.
Also BizTalk requires table schemas in order to perform CRUD operations.

Is there any other way to create BizTalk schemas other than through Navision where tables are exposed as service?

Answer (score 0):

If by "Table schema" you do mean the database directly, you would use the WCF SQL Adapter: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd788523.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Using the WCF-SQL adapter you can access the tables; but if the tables are owned by Navision, to be SOA compliant, I would prefer to access the data through the WebService that Navison exposes.  That way, if you ever replace Navison, you are not locked to the table and data structure.

Comment: Correct that i can access the table schema using the SQL Adapter and Wcf.What i wanted to know is that any other way i can do it other than using Navision Web service or directly interacting with the Navision database.

Comment: You could create the schema by hand.  WCF-SQL adapter is just a help to build your xml.

Comment: @Bitmask _if you ever replace Navison_ you would have to reimplement entire web service engine to gain similar web service behavior